# Copying eclipse projects through command line?

Tags: eclipse, command-line

Does anyone know if it is possible to copy an existing project into a new, created workspace on the fly? I can create the workspace already through command line. I am thinking I either need to copy the whole project into another workspace (possible through command line?) or create a new project and copy the .classpath and .project folders.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, Richie

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of your two suggestions as long as you store relative paths in your files. I have doen both in the past.

I also put the .classpath and .project  files under version control and so can check a new project out anywhere with the same environment - This does mean that third party libraries need to be in the same place so can be an issue with many users.

Comment: Thank you, Do you know how I can do these through the command line and not gui?

Comment: Just copy the files and then open the project

Comment: I tried copying the whole project and the .metadata file.. but when i try to run the software it says the project does not exist, but when i manually go into the directory, it is listed, and it does have all of the files inside the project. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the issue is when i copy from the command line, just the project and .metadata files, its not recognized in the workspace as a project - but i can open up the GUI and import the project into the created workspace, but i don't think that can be done through the command line without writing a plugin

Comment: SOLUTION: For my situation, copying the whole workspace into a new workspace worked, as opposed to pulling out of the old workspace and putting into the new workspace.